# Integration with partial fractions and logarithm rule simplification

Tags: integration, logarithms, partial-fractions

I've been having some trouble understanding a simplification involving logarithms that I came across in my notes. It is at the end of a partial fraction integration problem.

$$I = \int \frac{2}{x(2x-1)}dx $$

$$\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;I = \int \frac{2}{x(2x-1)} dx = \frac{A}{x} + \frac{B}{2x-1} $$

$$\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;I = \int \frac{2}{x(2x-1)} dx = \frac{A(2x-1)+Bx}{x(2x-1)} $$

$$ \;2 = A(2x-1) + Bx $$

$$     \;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\; x: 0 = 2A + B  \;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;const: 2 = -A$$

$$\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\; A = -2\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;B = 4 $$

$$\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\; I = \int \frac{-2}{x} + \frac{4}{2x-1} dx $$
$$ \;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;I = -2lnx + 2ln(2x-1) + c $$

Then this is where my lecturer wrote what something I don't understand. I realise he defined A earlier on in the problem but that makes the equation incorrect doesn't it?

$$ I = ln\left[A\left(\frac{2x-1}{x}\right)^2\right] $$

The next step is my simplification, which somebody said is incorrect as I used a log rule incorrectly.
$$ I = lnx^{-2}+ln(2x-1)^2+c $$
$$ I = ln\left(\frac{(2x-1)^2}{(x)^2}\right) =  ln\left(\frac{(2x-1)}{(x)}\right)^2+c $$

Is the following correct (this is the rule I used):
$$-2ln(x) = ln(x^{-2}) = ln \left(\frac{1}{x^2}\right)$$

This is my first question here and it took me ages to write all this using mathjax. Is this the only way to write out equations here? Seems very laborious. Anyways, many thanks!

Comment: You know you might type your equations in somewhere that formats the latex for you and then cut and paste if you want to be lazy about your typing. I often write things out in [desmos](https://www.desmos.com/calculator) and then cut and paste because it has already converted the text into latex format.

Answer (score 1):

The rules that you use are correct.

But The final answer is true **iff** the problem was:
$$\int\frac{2}{x(2x-1)}dx = \ln{\left[A\left(\frac{2x-1}{x}\right)^2\right]}$$

But if the problem be what you wrote, the answer is a quite different:
$$\int\frac{2}{x(x-1)}dx = \ln{\left[A\left(\frac{x-1}{x}\right)^2\right]}$$

If it was a typo, you are right at all.

And about make constant $c$ to coefficient $A$. Since $\log$ is a onto function, there is $A$ that $c=\log A$.

Comment: Sorry you're right, that was a typo, I missed out the 2 in the x(2x-1)

Comment: Ive just looked back at the video of him solving the problem and he gestures to the +c and says im going to bundle that in together, and then writes the A in the bracket. Could you explain how the A is being used?

Comment: You can do that because the $\log$ is an ONTO function.

Comment: Thank you for your help. Ive never heard of an ONTO function, and after reading a bit about this type of function im still not sure how it applies. I know the definition of an ONTO function is "a function f from a set X to a set Y is surjective, or a surjection, if for every element y in the codomain Y of f there is at least one element x in the domain X of f such that f(x) = y". So how does this apply to the way he has manipulated the constant? I dont understand how he has used the fact that this is an ONTO function, to express c in terms of log A. Thanks

Comment: It concludes directly by definition! Just suppose $\log : \mathbb{R^{> 0}} \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}$, and use the surjectivity property.